# Mongoose schema definition

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am a beginner with `MongoDB` and trying to learn `MEAN` Stack. So I am using [`Mongoose`](https://mongoosejs.com/) as the ORM

I read that MongoDB is a NoSQL database, but while using `Mongoose` as ORM, I am asked to create a schema first. Why is it so? There shouldn't be a schema ideally as MongoDB is a NoSQL database.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Schema is just to ensure that you maintain consistency in your db

Answer (score 1):

Mongoose is an orm on top of mongodb , if you are using core mongodb you need not create any schema , you can just dump any data you want , but in mongoose you have a schema so that you can i have some basic key value pair for advanced searching and filtering and you can anytime update the schema. Or If you want to go schemaless and dump whatever the response is you can use a schema type like this var someSchema = {data:Object} and drop all your data in this data key and then you can easily extract whatever JSON data is inside your id field.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

    module.exports = mongoose.model('twitter', {
        created_at:{
            type:Date
        },
        dump:{
            type:Object
        }

    });
```

In the above example dump is used to save whatever JSON I get as a response from twitter api and created_at contains only the creating date of tweet , so I have the entire data , but if i want to search tweets of a particular date I can search it using a find query on created_at and this query will be lot faster and here I have a fixed structure and a knowledge about what to expect of a find query each time a run one, So this is one of the benefit of using the mongoose orm i.e I don't lose data but I can maximise my searching ability by creating appropriate keys.

So basically mongoose is an ORM db , it  offers you relational db features like creating foreign keys , not strictly  foreign keys but you can create something like an id reference to another schema and later populate the field by the id associated parameters when you fetch data using your find query , also a relational schema is easy to manage , what mongoose does is it gives a JSON/BSON based db the power of relational db and you get best of both the world i.e you can easily maintain new keys or you don't need to worry about extracting each and every data from your operation and placing it properly/inserting it , you just need to see that your keys and values match , as well as you have flexibility in update operations while having a schema or table structure.